# Setting os.Mkdir permissions

Tags: go

I'm trying to create directories with certain permissions using os.Mkdir but I cannot make it work, for some reason.

My test program is:

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "os"
)

func main() {                 
    err := os.Mkdir("testdir", 0775)
    if err != nil {              
        log.Print(err)
    }
}
```

However, the created directory has the default 0755 permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Jan 10 10:14 testdir
```

A chmod from the shell works just fine, so I'm not sure why the Go program is not working.

Comment: What does appear when you run the `umask` command ?

Comment: 0022 is what it says

Comment: with umask 0022 works for me when after create file add permision `os.Chmod("testdir", 0777)`, but I'm not sure if it's good solution.

Comment: Yes, that's about interaction with the `umask` value of the current process and hence has nothing to do with neither Go nor StackOverflow in general. Please read a good introductory book on working in a Unix environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating a file, Unix-like system use a permission mask (umask) to create the default permissions.

With a `umask` value of `0022`, new directories will be created with permissions `0755` at most. New files will have permissions `0644` at most.

If you want to create a new directory with permissions `0775`, then you have to set your umask value to `0002`.

An other way of working this around is to modify the permissions after creating the file : Create it with default permissions with `os.Mkdir`, then modify those permissions with `os.Chmod`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however in my Go program I specify that I want 0775 permissions for the created file, and it is not working. Maybe it doesn't work and I have to change it later but it seems awkward to have that non-functional option.

Comment: `os.Mkdir` can't create files with permision greater than mask, but `os.Chmod` can?

Comment: @siritinga And that's exactly your problem : The OS prevents you from creating a directory with permissions 0775. I just tried modifying the umask from 0022 to 0002 (running `umask 0002`) on my laptop and I assure you it works. This is a Unix thing, not Go's fault.

Comment: @Iwan `os.Chmod` modifies permissions on an existing file, `os.Mkdir` creates a new file. The `umask` applies only on the creation operation (hopefully), that's why chmoding after creating works.

Comment: @Iwan Glad I could help :)

Comment: @T.Claverie I understand what you say, and I suppose I have to use Chmod, but then maybe it is a problem in Go because it says that "Mkdir creates a new directory with the specified name and permission bits", so if it isn't setting the bits nor returning an error, it is not what the documentation says. If Mkdir always creates the directories based on the umask, why you can give the file permissions to Mkdir?

Comment: @siritinga: Go is doing exactly what it says it's doing here, and is requesting the file creating with the permissions you set. Your OS is "masking" the permissions with the umask outside of Go's control. That's just how POSIX systems work, and you can't get by for long without understanding the underlying systems you're using.

Comment: @siritinga, see [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/umask.html) and [that](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/umask.html) documents which define `umask` behaviour in POSIX.